# UseStyles is not a function when giving the value by makeStyles - mui@4

Tags: javascript, material-ui

This is the console Error I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: useStyles is not a function
    at Dashboard (agentDashboard.js:48:1)
    //////////// Other Information /////////
```

AgentDashboard.js (It's not the whole file just the error-related stuff is mentioned):

```
// @material-ui/core
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

export default function Dashboard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const useStyles = makeStyles();
  return (
    /// Code ///
  );
}
```

My versions of MUIs:

```
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.13.7",
"@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
```

Comment: `const differentName = makeStyles();`

Comment: What Konrad meant to say is that you need to use a different name for the variable that calls `makeStyles()`. The variable `useStyles` is conflicting with the `useStyles()` call in the `classes` variable.